# Stripe CarElement not visible in React js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, stripe-payments

Below is my code for a checkout page where i have the CardElement and Iam processing the payment through stripe. It was working fine 2 days back but it has disappeared from the UI all of a sudden. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCQ23.png)Is there any changes Stripe has made in its CardElement package or Am I missing anything in my code?

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import Header from "./Header";
    import styled from "styled-components";
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { selectUserName, selectUserEmail } from "../features/userSlice";
    import {
      selectCart,
      selectCartTotalAmount,
      removeAllItems,
    } from "../features/cartSlice";
    import Orders from "./Orders";
    import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    import axios from "../axios";
    import { db } from "../firebase";
    
    function Checkout() {
      const userName = useSelector(selectUserName);
      const userEmail = useSelector(selectUserEmail);
      const cart = useSelector(selectCart);
      const cartTotalAmount = useSelector(selectCartTotalAmount);
      const history = useHistory();
      const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
      const [required, setRequired] = useState("");
      const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
      const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
      const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
      const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
      const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);
      const stripe = useStripe();
      const elements = useElements();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
      console.log("email", userEmail);
    
      const handlechange = (e) => {
        setAddress(e.target.value);
        // else {
        //   setRequired(false);
        // }
        //localStorage.setItem("address", address);
      };
    
      //   const goToPreview = () => {
      //     return <Preview address={address} />;
      //   };
    
      const validateAddress = () => {};
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const getClientSecret = async () => {
          const response = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: `/payments/create?total=${cartTotalAmount * 100}`,
          });
          setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret);
        };
        getClientSecret();
      }, [cart]);
    
      console.log("secret is", clientSecret);
    
      const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (address === "") {
          setRequired(true);
          setMsg("*Address is required!");
        } else {
          setProcessing(true);
          console.log(processing);
          const payload = await stripe
            .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
              payment_method: {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
              },
            })
            .then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
              db.collection("users")
                .doc(userEmail)
                .collection("orders")
                .doc(paymentIntent.id)
                .set({
                  cart: cart,
                  amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                  created: paymentIntent.created,
                  address: address,
                });
    
              setSucceeded(true);
              setError(null);
              setProcessing(false);
    
              dispatch(removeAllItems());
    
              history.replace("/orders");
            });
        }
      };
    
      const handleCardChange = (e) => {
        setDisabled(e.empty);
        setError(e.error ? e.error.message : "");
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Container>
            <Name>
              <p>Name : {userName}</p>
            </Name>
            <Email>
              <p>Email : {userEmail}</p>
            </Email>
            <Address>
              <p>Address : </p>
              <input type="text" onChange={handlechange} />
            </Address>
            <small>{msg}</small>
            <Order>
              <p>Order : </p>
            </Order>
            {cart.map((item) => (
              <OrderCard>
                <img src={item.image} />
                <p>{item.title}</p>
                <small>x</small>
                <p>{item.cartQuantity}</p>
              </OrderCard>
            ))}
            <Payment>
              Payment method :
              <form>
                <CardElement onChange={handleCardChange} />
              </form>
            </Payment>
            <Total>Total : ${cartTotalAmount}</Total>
            <button
              onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={processing || disabled || succeeded}
            >
              {processing ? "Processing" : "Place your order"}
            </button>
            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
          </Container>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Checkout;
    
    const Container = styled.div`
      padding-top: 70px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #feedf6, #fcf0e2);
      margin: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: center;
      button {
        margin-top: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        margin-left: 40rem;
        align-items: center;
      }
    
      small {
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-left: 20rem;
      }
    `;
    
    const Name = styled.div`
      margin-left: 35rem;
      /* margin-right: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px; */
    `;
    
    const Email = styled.div`
      margin-left: 35rem;
      /* margin-right: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px; */
    `;
    
    const Address = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-left: 35rem;
    
      h3 {
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-left: 5rem;
      }
      input {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
      }
    `;
    
    const Order = styled.div`
      margin-left: 35rem;
    `;
    
    const OrderCard = styled.div`
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-left: 35rem;
      img {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
      }
    
      small {
        margin-top: 17px;
        margin-left: 10px;
      }
      p {
        margin-left: 20px;
      }
    `;
    
    const Total = styled.div`
      margin-left: 35rem;
    `;
    
    const Payment = styled.div`
      margin-left: 35rem;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    
      form {
        margin-top: 10px;
        flex: 0.8;
        width: 600px;
        height: 40px;
      }
    `;
```

Comment: are there any errors in the browser devtools console?

Comment: can you try removing `flex` from a parent of CardElement?